# Comparison of two means within the same group

Tags: self-study, t-test, mean

I created a pretest before my main study. The goal of the pretest is to find two brands that are equal in terms of liking and familiarity. I computed the variables in SPSS and I was wondering if I have to do a t-test to confirm that the means are the same. To be more specific I found that for the brands Toyota and Lexus the means for attitude were almost the same (5.9 and 6.0)..is that enough to support that those two brands have the same attitude? Some people say that I have to do t-test to test if the means are the same but I don't think so cause I don't have 2 groups, just 27 people, and ALL of them answered the same questions.I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *could* do a t-test but I don't think it answers your question.  The thing is that with the usual t-test you test the null hypothesis that there is no difference, but you never accept the null.

If you want to do something statistical (beyond saying "look! 5.9 and 6.0 are really close!") then you want to look into equivalence testing. However, if you are just starting in statistics, that may be too advanced.

If you do want to do a t-test after all, you can do it because you have two sets of scores: 27 scores on the Toyota and 27 on the Lexus. Since they are from the same people, you could do a paired t-test.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply...Will I have to use only the two brands for the paired t-test or shall I do combinations of all brands I used? Also, I found a survey that had a similar pretest and they mentioned the means and that F<1. Do you know if this F is the so called F test?